# Goutte can't access this website because of SSL

Tags: php, symfony, curl, guzzle, goutte

I'm using fabpot/goutte 3.2, trying this code to access a website and isn't working

```
    $client = new \Goutte\Client();

    $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array(
        'curl' => array(
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false),
    ));
    $client->setClient($guzzleClient);

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', "www.superpharm.pl/sklepy");
    $crawler->filter('body')->each(function ($node) {
        print $node->text() . "\n";
    });
```

Getting this error:

```
In CurlFactory.php line 186:

  [GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException]                                      
  cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused (s  
  ee http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

This is working:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.superpharm.pl/sklepy");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $html;
```

This is working too (without goutte client):

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET', 'www.superpharm.pl/sklepy', ['verify' => false]);
    echo $res->getBody();
```

Anyone knows why isn't working with goutte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client used by Goutte first attempts to get the absolute URI based on the $uri argument. Because you have omitted the scheme from your URI (i.e. `https://`) the client transforms it to this:

```
http://localhost/www.superpharm.pl/sklepy
```

The solution is to simply change your URI to include the scheme like so:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', "https://www.superpharm.pl/sklepy");
```